# How to disable mailing in Odoo.sh

Tags: odoo, odoo.sh

I'm trying to create all Odoo project users and i don't want to send email reset password.
How to disable mailing in odo.sh version 14 for all Odoo notifications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a mail server with name "localhost" and void user and password refuse all mail in Odoo SH.

Then, ensure you "archive" all your other mail servers or set their priority to a much higher number than this one.

Once you're ready to re-enable outgoing mail, ensure you manually visit the outbound email queue as the "Super User" so you can delete any outgoing notifications from the queue or they will still get sent once you re-enable your real server.

Comment: Or just configure every user to getting no emails anymore? Every user can set this up in his preferences (upper right corner). An admin can do that on the users form page "Preferences". Just set the setting "Notification" to "Handle in Odoo" instead of "Handle by Emails".

Comment: This option are disabled because I need to block it before bulk importing users for a test migration, so I don't send them emails.